# Find elements in a paired elements list using another list (Python)

Tags: python, list

I have two list: one is a selected list of about 2 millions chromosome positions (e.g. [9866, 9899, 10257....]). The other one is a paired list with chromosome position and pvalue (e.g [(9866, 0.001),(9899, 0.05)]...)

I would like to retrieve the p-value for the selected 2 millions chromosome. My code is currently as follows:

```
    Selection = []
    for i in selected indices:
      for x in list(range(len(T3))):
         if T3[x][0] == i:
             b = T3[x][0],T3[x][1]
             Selection.append(b)
```

Is there a fastest way to do this? Obviously this is very slow as it iterates for each line in T3 and for each item in selected indices. I was thinking of using the set function but my T3 list is a list of paired elements

Comment: why do you use your first list if you have the positions in your second one ? I d'ont get what you want to do. Show your expected output please

Comment: I have the position in the second list but there are about 1.4 billions positions and i only want to select the 2 millions from the other list

Comment: Now it's more clear ...

Comment: is the pair-list ordered? faster searches than iteration over the whole list can be implemented if it is ordered such as getting the center element, determining if its bigger or smaller and then getting the center of the correspondig half array (be careful with memory management with this method)

Comment: 1.4 billion data elements might require space optimizations rather than just runtime one... I added another solution in my answer that might be better tailored for your case.

Answer (score 2):

Likely, a faster approach will be to make a mapping from position to pvalue:

```
mapping = dict(T3)
```

Then use that mapping:

```
selected_pvalues = [mapping[pos] for pos in positions]
```

Note: `mapping` will remove any duplicate chromosome positions and only keep the last one in the original list.

Comment: T3 is 1.4 billion entries, there should be faster methods than this if the "selecting" operation only needs to be done once

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks that worked great! Will remember to vote up once I have enough reputation

Comment: @Adirio Not sure why but this was surprisingly fast in fact

Comment: @CenCG you can upvote now and it won't appear for now but when you get to the rep threshold it will automatically be applied

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether the first list holds exactly the same values as the first elements of all the pairs in the second (I assume they are not, or there is no point in having them).

You should convert the pairs list into a dictionary, and then you will get each value in (usually) O(1) runtime complexity.

**Edit**

Although the above should work quite fine, your specific case might also cause memory issues, as you are dealing with billions of records. In a case that converting the pairs' list into a dictionary takes too much memory and degrades the overall performance, you can use another approach -

Change the first (smaller) list into a set. Then, go over the pairs' list, and for each element, check if it is in that set. This way you will still have one pass over the larger structure, but you will require much less space.

Comment: turning it into a set may not be wanted as he may want to have duplicated entries in the list and because it will use the pair-list order instead of the selected items order and they may differ

Comment: In the cases you suggest (which I am not sure that are required by the OP), we can solve that by using - instead of a set - a dictionary, whose key is the position and value is a (lists of) the index(es) in the original list. That will still make sure that the memory required is smaller in order of magnitudes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to store another identifier for the second lists' chromosomes. This would allow you to build a dictionary instead of the second list. For example:

```
myTrillionsChromosomes = {
    'chromosomeId': pValue,
    ...
}
```

> **Edit:** That is, if you can actually control the construction of those lists. Another answer describes how to convert a list of tuples into a dictionnary, but given the sheer size of that list it might not be very wise.

Then, you merely have to look up the p-value in the dictionary, which is done in constant time.

```
selection = []
for id in identifiersList:
    selection.append((id, myTrillionsChromosomes[id])
```

Comment: Deleting comments as they offer no information now, you should do the same. Downvote also removed.